# Programatically record audio output from web page using jS or html5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-recording

Is there any way to programatically capture the audio being played from a webpage using html5, jS, or something else and create a mp3/wav file out of it? I know of the web audio API, but I've only been able to find information on recording audio from microphone input, rather than output of a web page.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Web Audio API to record the output of any Web Audio node, not just microphone input. If the webpage you want to record audio from is using the Web Audio API to generate sound, then you can definitely use the Web Audio API to record it (check out Recorder.js).

If the sound is being played from html  elements, you can turn it into a Web Audio node and record it. Check this out: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs

Comment: I'm glad to help. If you feel that this answers your question, please select it as the chosen answer.