# Record sound played back using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, media, audio-recording

How to record an audio being played through my own page?
I want to use `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it works but I hope this helps:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs from [Programatically record audio output from web page using jS or html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263132/programatically-record-audio-output-from-web-page-using-js-or-html5)

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but the example of the second link helped me.