# Record audio from site and save it (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, record

What I ultimately want to do is record sounds from the site (e.g. a song playing in the background), and save the file locally. I've been looking for examples or documentation but all I find is record the audio from the microphone.

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far? See [ask].

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 record audio to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file)

Comment: It's not duplicate. He doesn't want to record from the microphone.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263132/programatically-record-audio-output-from-web-page-using-js-or-html5